# Is there a way to replace the content of the first argument passed to ReactDOM.render() from a child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to replace everything from `<Router history={hashHistory}>` to `</Router>` with just a simple message such as `<div>You don't have access to this section of the site.</div>` based on certain conditions in MyApp component and re-render the DOM? See code below:

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Redirect, Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

import MyApp from './ReactCode/MyApp';
import UsersComponent from './ReactCode/Users/UsersComponent';
import ProductsComponent from './ReactCode/Products/ProductsComponent';

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
           <Route path="/" component={MyApp}>
           <Route path="/:link" component={UsersComponent} />
           <Route path="/:link/products" component={ProductsComponent} />
           <Redirect from="/:link/:product" to="/:link/products/?id=:product" />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root-container'));`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have a variable that represents that condition (let's call it `condition`), you can use it to put different components into a route.For example, you could use `condition` and a component `Denied`, which just renders `<div>You don't have access to this section of the site.</div>` to do something like this:

```js
<Route path="/:link" component={condition ? UsersComponent : Denied} />
```

If you find yourself needing to do that a lot, you can even make a which includes that protection which you can use instead of Route:

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({ condition, path }) => <Route path={path} component={condition ? UsersComponent : Denied} />
```

That way, you can use `ProtectedRoute` instead of `Route` whenever you need to add that message.

**EDIT**

If you can only access your condition in `componentDidMount`, then you can  set that condition in local state using `setState`:

```js
// this should go somewhere in your component to define a default state
// here the default state is false, edit it to meet your needs
state = { condition: false }; 

componentDidMount() {
    // however you're getting your condition goes here
    // sets this.state.condition to whatever your condition is
    this.setState({ condition }); 
}
```

You can then pass `this.state.condition` to `ProtectedRoute` in your render function:

```js
<ProtectedRoute path="/:link" condition={this.state.condition} />
```

Note that this method will call `render` twice [as per the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and can cause performance issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, my condition is only available from inside the componentDidMount() of MyApp component so I want to be able to dynamically replace all the <Router history={hashHistory}>...</Router> in the index.js with that message once the DOM is mounted. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I don't believe so. AFAIK, you can't change `render` from `componentDidMount` directly. That said, you could try doing something  like checking for the condition in `componentDidMount` and if it is true, setting that in local state (`this.setState()` to be accessed in `render` with `this.state`. What is your condition that it is only accessible in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Your suggestion sounds like a solution. Could you give me a code example of doing that?